# What can be inferred from Simple Random Sampling?

Tags: sampling, sample, population

Suppose I have access to a population data set. I then perform **Simple Random Sampling** on this data set to pull a sample. I perform some tests to see if the population data set and the sample data set come from the same population. This results in verification that they did come from the same population.

Since **Simple Random Sampling** is performed and is successful, can I infer that there is no dependency between each action based on their order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "each action"? Your question appears to describe only one sampling operation.

Answer (score 0):

The "success" comes in when you are able to perform SRS without losing any observations because of non-participation, attrition, or other kinds of issues where you were not able to get the observations u wished to obtain.

If you actually succeeded in performing SRS, there is no sense in testing the difference between the population and sample. This test will always be rejected at the Type I error rate or alpha level, which is often 5%.

Comment: This is true. However, my question was "can I infer that there is no dependency between each observation based on their order? "

Comment: If you did SRS, then yes.

Comment: Is there a better way of testing if there is a dependency between subsequent observations rather than my hacked together method?

Comment: You mention no "hacked together method".   If you are saying that you tried to do simple random sampling, but are not sure if you did, you'll have to be explicit about you did.  But then you must change the title and description of your question.